# Worker log file gets mangled when log_directory is set

Tags: python-3.x, dask, slurm, dask-distributed, dask-jobqueue

I used to have the worker logs as such:

```
./slurm-<id>.out
...
```

So I wanted to have SLURMCluster writes the worker logs in a separate directory (as opposed to the current working dir), so I provided "log_directory" as an input argument as such.

```
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
c = SLURMCluster(queue_name, log_directory="dirA")
c.scale_up(1)
```

And the logs end up like this:

```
./dirA/dask-worker-<id>.out
./dirA/dask-worker-<id>.err
```

And all the worker logs are piped to the .err file while the .out file is empty.

What am I missing in the SLURMCluster configuration to set it correctly, such that the .out should contain the logs and the .err should contain worker errors.

Comment: the title no longer makes sense without any context to what log and log_directory is, when the reference to SLURMCluster is removed

Comment: Could you check the job submission script created by dask-jobqueue (print(cluster.job_script())), normally, setting log_directory will add two options to the batch submission script: #SBATCH -e log_directory/worker-id.err and #SBATCH -o log_directory/worker-id.err. In the previous setup, did you have the logs in the .out file?